# Removing id attribute to link from my url

Tags: html

For some reason unknown to me the id attribute to link to a section of my webpage gets stuck in the url after clicking on it.

```html
<a href="#second" button class="btn">Click Here To Pre-Order</button></a>

<a id="second"></a>
```

To see a live example of what I mean you can please visit [plushvip.com[1](http://www.plushvip.com), click on the first button to see what I mean.

Any ideas?

Comment: Define "*gets stuck in the url after clicking*".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`#1`: That's how it is supposed to work
`#2`: As noted in the other answer that is called hashes, and you would use jquery to fix it. I like this little script it removes the hashes, and has a nice scroll animation instead of a jump:
JQuery:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
    $(".scroll").click(function(event) {
       event.preventDefault();
       $('html,body').animate( { scrollTop:$(this.hash).offset().top } , 1000);
    });
});
```

HTML:

```
<a href="#second" class="scroll" >
<button class="btn">Click Here To Pre-Order</button>
</a>
```

Demo:
http://jsfiddle.net/ImagineStudios/c604vbrn/11/

Comment: Thank you for sharing! I added the JQuery code that you provided and replaced the href with your but it doesn't scroll smoothly and still shows the #id. I'm wondering if I'm missing something to make the JQuery work?

Comment: My fault, try it now!

Comment: Cool! Do I need to add something like a link to JQuery 1.11.0 within the head of my .html doc.?

Comment: <script type="text/javascript" src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.0.js"></script> Is all you need

Answer (score 0):

Try using this snippet.

```
<button class="btn"><a href="#bottom">Click Here To Pre-Order</a></button>

<a id="bottom"></a>
```

Comment: Thank you for your help...It works however it turns the text within the button to the link, not the button. So the text within the button gets underlined and you actually have to click on the text within instead of the button itself. Any thoughts on this?

Comment: Actually I spoke to soon...the #id is still in the browser.

Comment: That how it works. If you want to remove that, write an .htaccess file for every particular ID.

Comment: Maybe this'll help you if you know AJs ... http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/826753/Removing-sharp-From-URL-in-AngularJS

Comment: Thank you so much! I'll have a look now :)

Answer (score 0):

That's how hashes work. If you reload the page browser tries to find an element that has the current hash as it's id and focuses on it. If that's not what you want, you should prevent the default action of the `click` event, then the document's hash won't be updated, but then you should select the target element using JavaScript and change the scroll position of the window according to top offset of the target element.

And your markup is invalid. Where is the opening `button` tag and why a `button` element in an `a` element?

Comment: Thank you for your help and thank you for pointing out the invalid markup. I'm a novice when it comes to coding, just started learning html/css so I have a long way to go :) I'm very new to js so this is above my level at the moment, I guess I'll just have to deal with the hash.