# How to remove same page hyperlink name from url?

Tags: javascript, html

My webpage is long so in the heading I have linked buttons to different parts of my page. But when I click them, it changes from, for example, www.helloworld.com to www.helloworld.com/#part1 . How do I remove this "part1"? I know how to remove .html .php , but i dont know how to remove this.

```
<li><a href="#part1" class="current"><strong>Story</strong></a></li>
```

This is the button and it is linked to

```
<div id="part1"></div>
```

Thanks.

Comment: It is unclear what you are trying to convey. If you are going to set #part1 in href then it will surely be added in URL. Try adding "javascript:;" on href and set click event.

Comment: Your Problem will be solve here.
[Click here][1]  






  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26823768/removing-id-attribute-to-link-from-my-url

Answer (score 0):

OKay, if you wanna make it smooth-scroll and remove the link follow the page, you can do so only by using JavaScript. Either add a `return false` to the `onclick` event of the anchor or provide an alternate mechanism:

```
<li><a href="#part1" class="current" onclick="return false;"><strong>Story</strong></a></li>
```

The above code doesn't add the `#part1` to the URL, but it also doesn't let you navigate to the `<div>`. So, you need to do this:

```
<li><a href="#part1" class="current" onclick="window.scrollTo(0, document.getElementById('part1').offsetTop); return false;"><strong>Story</strong></a></li>
```

The `return false;` will make the link not add the extra part. And the `window.scrollTo` navigates the page to the right position.

To make this scalable for all the internal links, for a relatively new browser, that supports `document.queryStringAll`, do this:

```
document.queryStringAll('a[href^="#"]').onclick = function (e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  window.scrollTo(0, document.getElementById(this.attribute("href").substr(1)).offsetTop);
  return false;
}
```